# In Visual Studio, can you add a folder-based project in a solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Visual Studio *finally* has the ability to open folder-only projects, which makes it great for simple web sites that serve from the file system, etc.  However, I can't find a way to add one of these projects to my existing solution. Whenever I try opening it, it tells me to close it.

So, how can you add a folder-based project to Visual Studio solution? Or can you?